# The structure “V-ing + of + noun”

Tags: gerunds, phrase-structure

> Chewing of food
> Chew food

I am wondering if they are the same.

When and why do we use the structure [ *V-ing + "of" + noun* ] ?

Comment: Hello Tony, and welcome to ELL! On this site, people asking questions are required to show they've tried to find the answer themselves. What do you already know about those structures? Why do you think they might be the same?

Comment: Try putting the two expressions into sentences and see if that helps.